# what does @{ $hds{$cl}{connlist} } do?

Tags: perl

```
%hds = ();

%hd_var = &hd_var( @{ $hds{$cl}{connlist} }, @{ $hds{$cl}{welllist} } );
```

I'm new to PERL and I need to crack some code in order to speed up the optimization, so I'm trying to first figure out what the code is doing.

What is this doing:

```
@{ $hds{$cl}{connlist} }
```

`hd_var` is an empty hash before this statement, so what does `$hds{$cl}{connlist}` do? `$cl` is equal to "network", so what does `$hds{"network"}{connlist}` do? It's not assigning anything, so is it creating a hash of hashes with empty string as its value? I'm not sure and would love for an expert to help me out.

Answer (score 2):

In this code

```
@{ $hds{$cl}{connlist} }
```

The `$hds{$cl}{connlist}` is expected to be a array reference, and the `@{ }` around it dereferences the array reference.

This would be the same as saying:

```
my $arrayref = $hds{$cl}{connlist};
my @array    = @{$arrayref};
# or
my @array    = @$arrayref;
```

Comment: thanks for the help so far. i understand that @{ } derefences a list reference, but what does $hds{$cl}{connlist} do?  my $listref = $hds{$cl}{connlist}; creates a reference to it, but i don't understand what this part does. hds was previously an empty hash.

Comment: It's called autovivification.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification  Better to read that than me come up with an explanation for it.

Comment: @AndyLester: Would you consider changing the names of your example variables? They are arrays (and array refs) rather than lists (and list refs). Using names containing "list" could well encourage the (incorrect) belief that arrays and lists in Perl are the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Talk about 'throwing in at the deep end'.

Note that `&hd_var` is a function, separate from the hash `%hd_var`.

The first argument to the function is an array; so is the second.  The `@{ … }` notation means that the `…` is an array reference.  There's a hash, `%hds`, which is indexed by `$cl` and then `connlist` to generate an array reference, which is dereferenced in the cal.  The second argument is similar, except the second subscript is `welllist` instead of `connlist`.  It is likely that between the two of them, they are a list of machines which need to be processed.

---

Some sample code that emulates what I see of your data structures:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $cl = "network";

my %hds = ( "network" => { connlist => [ 'mach1', 'mach2', 'oatmeal' ],
                           welllist => [ 'steeple', 'spire', 'windcock' ],
                         }
          );

print "@{$hds{$cl}{connlist}}\n";
print "@{$hds{$cl}{welllist}}\n";

sub hd_var  # Function name same as variable name - not usually a good idea
{
    return grep { !/i/ } @_;
}

my %hd_var = &hd_var( @{ $hds{$cl}{connlist} }, @{ $hds{$cl}{welllist} } );

for my $key (keys %hd_var)
{
    print "$key = $hd_var{$key}\n";
}
```

Sample output:

```
mach1 mach2 oatmeal
steeple spire windcock
oatmeal = steeple
mach1 = mach2
```

Note that although `%hd_var` is emptied in your code, it may as well be created as shown in my code.  The `%hds` hash must be populated for the code to do anything useful.

The code above is fragile; it converts the array returned by `&hd_var` into a hash, but does not ensure that there is an even number of elements in the array that is returned.  With the function as written and the data as shown, it works OK, but it could easily break.  It just gives you an idea of what could be going on in the surrounding code.

Comment: thanks so much for the help! what do you mean 'is indexed by $cl and then connlist to generate an array reference'. is it creating a  second hash with connlist as the second index with an empty value?

Comment: It's really hard to tell without more of the code.  I'll try to dummy up stuff that could do the job.  You need a solid working knowledge of references, hashes and arrays (lists) to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

(It's "Perl", not "PERL")

```
@{ $hds{$cl}{connlist} }
```

This code expects you to have a hash called `%hds`. This hash is expected to contain a key matching whatever is currently in `$cl`. The expression `$hds{$cl}` gets you the value associated with that key in the hash.

That value is expected to be a hash reference, as we then look in the referenced hash for the key `connlist` (that's a literal value). We get the value associated with that key, which is expected to be an array reference that we can dereference to get to the array that we need.

Another way to look at it is to break it down into separate statements like this.

```
my $hash_ref = $hds{$cls};
my $arr_ref  = $hash_ref->{connlist};
my @array    = @{ $arr_ref };
```

You might also get a better view of this data structure by using Data::Dumper;

```
use Data::Dumper;

print Dumper \%hdc;
```

Does that help at all?

Comment: yes it helps a lot. but %hds was empty before this statement. %hds = ();. so since the code expects a key matching $cl, but doesn't find it, i guess its creating all of this dynamically here?

Comment: Well, yes, it'll create `$hds{$cls}` which will contain a reference to a new hash. And `$hds{$cl}{connlist}` which will contain a reference to a new (and therefore empty) array. Seems like a rather confusing way to go about it though.

Comment: @jcmoon: Note that you have `%hd_var = ();` in the question (which is actually unnecessary since you immediately assign a new value to it); you don't show how `%hds` is created, but it must already have data in it.